# Error on marker osmdroid offline map

Tags: android, marker, osmdroid

i use of osmdroid offline map on android.
i get some location on my server(use json) and show with marker on map,some times it is good,i dont have problem,but some times i have error like this:

> Marker: layout/bonuspack_bubble not found in [packge name]

Code:

```
@Override  
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

         Helper hel=new Helper(root.getContext());
        List<Location> all=hel.GetAll();



        for (Location loctxt : all)
        {
      final  Marker m1=new Marker(map);   

          String[] str=loctxt.loc.split(",");

          GeoPoint CompaniesPoint=new GeoPoint(Double.parseDouble(str[0]), Double.parseDouble(str[1]));

          m1.setPosition(CompaniesPoint);
          m1.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p1));   
          m1.setTitle(loctxt.id+"");
          m1.setSubDescription(loctxt.name);

            map.getOverlays().add(m1);
            m1.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0, MapView arg1) {
                    Log.d("M1 Value:::", m1.getTitle());

                    get_img(m1.getTitle());        
                    int[] loc=new int[2];
                    root.getLocationInWindow(loc);
                    p=new Point();
                arg1.getProjection().toPixels(arg0.getPosition(),p);
                    if(p!=null)
                        showPopup(root.getContext(), p);  

                    return false;
                }
            });

          }
```

Answer (score -2):

In short, you don't have the Marker bubble layout (`bonuspack_bubble.xml`) included in the resources of your project.

For more info, follow the very first [OSMBonusPack tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_0), related to Markers.